# htacces rewrite on urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi can anyone help me i want to rewrite some bad php urls in htaccess
I have urls on my site which looks like this:
http://www.spellentuin.nl/puzzel-spellen.php?pag=2&order= 
and so on for every following page they must show up like this:
http://www.spellentuin.nl/puzzel-spellen2.php
(order= must dissapear and next page must be puzzel-spellen3.php and so on)
What do i need to put in htaccess to get this done and do i need to put same code for every page i have because i have a lot of different game category pages? At this moment google does not index any of those following pages. If you have better ideas than puzzel-spellen2.php please suggest also.

Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule is pretty straight forward (if you just have this case)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^puzzel-spellen([0-9]+).php$ /puzzel-spellen.php?pag=$1&order=
```

In order to use this, you have also to modify every link. This could be done by register an output filter like so (this has to be placed at the very beginning of your scripts - before you output anything)

```
ob_start(function($str) {
    return preg_replace(
        '/\/puzzel-spellen\.php\?pag=([0-9]+)&order=/',
        'puzzel-spellen$1.php',
        $str);
});
```

But the better solution would be to modify every link. I.e.

```
'<a href="puzzel-spellen.php?pag=' . $i . '&amp;order=' . urlencode($_GET['order'])
```

just becomes (as you dont want order to be included)

```
'<a href="puzzel-spellen' . $i . '.php'
```

Comment: Hi Philipp i put this in htaccess but it does not do much please see http://www.spellentuin.nl/puzzel-spellen.php and following pages many thanks for your help!

Comment: That code doesn't replace anything in your html files. It just handles requests. If you just call http://www.spellentuin.nl/puzzel-spellen2.php, you should see the effect

Comment: i see but that just makes a duplicate page with the right name and does not rewrite the original url like it should be. I also have the same problem with all other game category pages it is not just the page puzzel-spellen also http://www.spellentuin.nl/denk-spellen.php?pag=2&order= and so on.

Comment: Yeah - because of that, I told you, that you have to modify every link to puzzle-spellen.php. An other way would be to register an output filter and replace the links before you send the content to the browser - but imho this isn't a clean solution

Comment: How do i modify every link to puzzel-spellen.php i am a newbie on this? And is there other solution ? http://www.spellentuin.nl/actie-spelletjes.php has 52 pages

Comment: This is a piece of the code in puzzel spellen maybe change something ?  $sPagString .= $i == $iHuidige ? '<span class="on">' . $i . '</span> ' : ($i == 1 ? '<a href="puzzel-spellen.php">1</a> ' : '<a href="puzzel-spellen.php?pag=' . $i . '&amp;order=' . urlencode($_GET['order']) . '">' . $i . '</a> ');

Comment: So basically these two lines need to be changed can you do this for me please i get error after error: $sPagString .= $i == $iHuidige ? '<span class="on">' . $i . '</span> ' : ($i == 1 ? '<a href="puzzel-spellen.php">1</a> ' : '<a href="puzzel-spellen.php?pag=' . $i . '&amp;order=' . urlencode($_GET['order']) . '">' . $i . '</a> ');
                              }
                              
                              $sPagString .= '<a href="puzzel-spellen.php?pag=' . $iTotaal . '&amp;order=' . urlencode($_GET['order']) . '">&raquo;</a>';

Comment: Line 1:   $sPagString .= $i == $iHuidige ? '<span class="on">' . $i . '</span> ' : ($i == 1 ? '<a href="puzzel-spellen.php">1</a> ' : '<a href="puzzel-spellen.php?pag=' . $i . '&amp;order=' . urlencode($_GET['order']) . '">' . $i . '</a> ');

Comment: Line 2:  $sPagString .= '<a href="puzzel-spellen.php?pag=' . $iTotaal . '&amp;order=' . urlencode($_GET['order']) . '">&raquo;</a>';

Comment: i changed line 1 but get syntax error "" what's wrong in that line Philipp please help me? $sPagString .= $i == $iHuidige ? '<span class="on">' . $i . '</span> ' : ($i == 1 ? '<a href="puzzel-spellen.php">1</a> ' : '<a href="puzzel-spellen' . $i . '.php'">' . $i . '</a> ');

Comment: seems, you have and `'` to much after `.php` - should be `'.php">` instead of `'.php'">`

Comment: Ok figured it out was little syntax error in your code it works fine now, thanks for help! So for every different category page i also need to make an extra line in htaccess?

Comment: in your case,  this would be the easiest way

Comment: Now i changed this another problem arrived if you click on one the 3 grey buttons it only orders the first page, not the following pages

Comment: (best gewaardeerd button) http://www.spellentuin.nl/puzzel-spellen.php?order=score

Comment: i put back urlencode($_GET['order']) in the two lines to create different link s on the pageurls of the 3 grey buttons the problem is that those links as from page 2 do not work.

Comment: for instance http://www.spellentuin.nl/puzzel-spellen2score.php must be http://www.spellentuin.nl/puzzel-spellen.php?pag=2&order=score in order to work. Is there an option to just rewrite those page urls? They are nofollow so no problem in google.

Comment: Solved in htaccess with it works so i think it is good: RewriteRule ^puzzel-spellen([0-9]+)score.php$ /puzzel-spellen.php?pag=$1&order=score